# Excel bug with mouse cursor

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10, mouse

Recently my colleague noticed problem while working in Excel:

- when she is trying to select more cells it doesn't do it, it selects only one and drags it around
- when she tries to click on cell to select it it appears as she double clicked it
- when she wants to close document she can't, nothing happens (she can't close it on **x** or on File/Close, or right click on toolbar icon)

We have tried to change mouse but it's the same. And it happens only in Excel.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Make sure she has not accidentally enabled **StickyKeys**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I thought **StickyKeys** were meant only for keyboard

Comment: Repair/reinstall Excel?